# I have a problem sending an email to a registered user using the Laravel framework

Tags: laravel, image, email

When a user registers, he receives an email as he has registered in the application.
In my development environment, using mailtrap.io if you receive the image of the project to which you have registered, but when I send it from the web in production this image is not displayed.

This is the code I use to send the mail and also to send the variables necessary to display the image.
EnviarEmail.php:

```
public $usuario;
    public $proyecto;
    public $ruta_imagen;
    public $logo;

    public function __construct(Usuario $usuario, $proyecto, $ruta_imagen, $logo)
    {
        $this->usuario = $usuario;
        $this->proyecto = $proyecto;
        $this->ruta_imagen = $ruta_imagen;
        $this->logo = $logo;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('Mail.mail')
                    ->from('developer@autoevaluaciononline.com')
                    ->subject('Confirmación de registro');
    }
```

Save user:

```
$proyecto_nombre = Proyecto::where('id', $id)->get(['titulo_proyecto']);
$proyecto = $proyecto_nombre[0]->titulo_proyecto;
$logo = "images/logos/logo-KRMedicine.png";
$ruta_imagen = "images/aspecto-proyecto/imagen_horizontal/".$proyecto_nombre[0]->titulo_proyecto."/".$imagen_banner_nombre[0]->nombre;
$email = $request->email;
$subject = "Confirmación de registro";
Mail::to($email)->send(new EnviarEmail($usuario,$proyecto, $ruta_imagen, $logo));
```

Catch mailtrap.io:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAXXl.jpg
Capture how you receive it from gmail:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECIWW.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using markdown.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mail

```
@component('mail::layout')
{{-- Header --}}
@slot('header')
@component('mail::header', ['url' => config('app.url')])
    AutoevaluaciónOnline
@endcomponent
@endslot
<img src="{{asset('images/aspecto-proyecto/imagen_horizontal/'.$proyecto.'/'.$nombre_banner)}}" alt="banner" width="auto">
{{--  Body  --}}
Ha finalizado con éxito el proceso de registro en el programa.


<p style="text-align: center;">{{ $proyecto }}.</p>


Acceda de nuevo utilizando el mail que nos ha indicado como usuario y la contraseña que ha asignado anteriormente.


En caso de querer restablecer la contraseña siga este enlace.


{{--  Footer  --}}
@slot('footer')
@component('mail::footer')
    © {{ date('Y')}} AutoevaluacionOnline. Todos los derechos reservados.
    <img src="{{asset($logo)}}" width="228px" height="51px">
@endcomponent
@endslot
@endcomponent
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not attaching the image to the email, instead, you just add a link for that image, so It's working on your local dev setup, but when you send the email from production, the image link is broken (because the image is only there in your system).

So host the image in some public server and give the full path eg:// http://example.com/path/to/abc.jpg as the image URL. Hope it helps

Comment: That same image is hosted in the application in production

Comment: Yes, in that case you can try providing the full path?

Comment: Of course. This is the route I receive from mailtrap.io: ```<img class="adapt-img" src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/aspecto-proyecto/imagen_horizontal/Trauma and Orthopaedics Update Course/banner curs.jpg" alt="Image" style="display: block;" width="560">```  and is from gmail: ```http://dev.autoevaluaciononline.com/images/aspecto-proyecto/imagen_horizontal/Trauma+and+Orthopaedics+Update+Course/banner+curs.jpg```

Comment: I understand why the image is not shown, it is because it contains spaces and from local it does not replace the spaces with '+', however when it is in production, in this case if you receive them from gmail the url replaces the spaces with '+ '